# Laravel appends child when referencing it in attribute function

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 8.x. im trying to access data from a related model in a getSeomthingAttribute() method. Let's say I want a array of all the names of the grand children my code looks something like this:

```php
public function getGrandChildrenNamesAttribute() {
        $names = [];
        foreach ($this->child->children as $grandChild) {
                array_push($names, $grandChild->name);
        }

        return $names;
    }
```

Now when i append the grandChildrenNames attribute to the model it also appends the whole $child attribute. I append the attribute like so:

```php
return Parent::find($id)->append('grand_children_names');
```

And returns like so:

```json
{
  name: "some name",
  age: 21,
  grand_children_names: [
    "name 1",
    "name 2",
    etc...
  ],
  child: {
    name: "child name"
    etc...
  },
}
```

How can I append `grand_children_names` without appending `$child`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot about `makeHidden()`.
That was the solution for me. I did the following when calling the parent model:

```php
return Parent::find($id)->append('grand_children_names')->makeHidden('child');
```

---

EDIT: Came across the same issue again where `makeHidden` was not an option. The better solution than using `makeHidden` is not using Eloquent's dynamic properties inside accessor methods or in models at all.

So instead write the code like this:

```php
public function getGrandChildrenNamesAttribute() {
    $names = [];
    foreach ($this->child()->get()->children as $grandChild) {
        array_push($names, $grandChild->name);
    }

    return $names;
}
```

Also couldve used pluck:

```php
public function getGrandChildrenNamesAttribute() {
    return $this->child()->children->pluck('name');
}
```